# Window title not showing correctly - electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I'm experiencing a weird bug with Electon on Windows 7 64bits.

Everything in the code is working just fine, but when I run the `.exe`, the window's title sometime (most of the time) shows up as "Electron" until I **pass something on top** of the window (then it magically morph into the title I intended)...

I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with my code (as I've tried just about everything I could find, and more ...) and everything to do with Windows Explorer (and my windows installation in general).

But, still, I am guessing that Electron shows up with a **default name** and then **update** the name from the title of the HTML page (or from any other place that it could be set).

So, I wonder where is that default name ? And, where can I find this taunting "Electron" and edit the heck out of it ?

I have already modified my `.exe` with *Resource Hacker*, so there is no trace of "Electron" right there ...

Do I need to **recompile it** ? And if, so, would you know where in the sources I could find that default "Electron" title ?

#### EDIT

All of this is happening inside the `dist` folder of `electron-prebuilt`. But, it's doing the same thing no matter where my app is and no matter how I run it. There is no code anywhere relevent to this issue really... I juste have the expected title in the head of my HTML... The main is vanilla Electron documentation, straight from GitHub...

Here is an image to better illustrate the issue:

[image: Problem illustrated]

Comment: How are you running your app? Did you have a local version of electron in your node_modules folder? Also show us your relevant code from main.js

Comment: Oh yes sorry I should have precised that : all of this is happening inside the dist folder of electron-prebuilt. But it's doing the same thing no matter where my app is and no matter how I lauch it. There is no code anywhere relevent to this issue really ... I juste havec the expected title in the head of my html ... the main is vanilla electron documentation, straight from gitHub ... nothing to see there i'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

So after a good research on the sources, I've found it here :

*electron/atom/browser/native_window.cc*

```
200 std::string title("Electron");
```

Now I think I will just have to modify the sources and build my own electron
///////////EDIT 2 ///////////
-I would very much appreciate any help on how to compile electron myself **///** found promising documentation right here : https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-windows.md .

-I am trying to build it following these instructions but I am getting an error :

```
C:\Users\LazyParia\Desktop\myElectron\electron>C:\Python27\2.7.7\python.exe scri
pt\bootstrap.py -v
Running in verbose mode
git submodule sync
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script\bootstrap.py", line 189, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "script\bootstrap.py", line 39, in main
    update_submodules()
  File "script\bootstrap.py", line 84, in update_submodules
    execute_stdout(['git', 'submodule', 'sync'])
  File "C:\Users\LazyParia\Desktop\myElectron\electron\script\lib\util.py", line
 173, in execute_stdout
    subprocess.check_call(argv, env=env)
  File "C:\Python27\2.7.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\2.7.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\2.7.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\2.7.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable

C:\Users\LazyParia\Desktop\myElectron\electron>
```

Would anyone know what this mean ? (btw : "Le fichier spécifié est introuvable" = the specified file cannot be found , or something like that)

////////////////////////////////////

So here we go, I will try that today (and come back to you with an edit and more precisions if it works) but I'm still interested in informations about this issue.
Thanks for reading me
-Lazy-

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the Electron windows title via the [win.setTitle(title) API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#winsettitletitle)?

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite in the same context, I run into a similar issue (the application title not refreshing unless you somehow get the window to "repaint").

The fault apparently lies in electron not working as expected unless when Aero is activated (eg when you have the Windows Classic theme running instead).

These hints were suggested to me by the [following thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/window-repaint-not-working-on-windows-7-enterprise-edition/28569) (and somewhat by [this bug report](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1821) too).

In my case, turning Aero back on again was "good enough". I realize though it won't quite solve the issue in every context.

For full reference, what led me to your post was an issue related to the title not updating dynamically on Windows (as you browse through the pages of my express-powered electron app).